# Grails: GORM and BitSets?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, object-persistence, bitset

I don't see anything in the [official documentation](http://grails.org/GORM) about unsupported persistence data types, so I'm working under the assumption that types available in the Groovy language should be handled. However, for the following domain class:

```
class DocGroupPermissions {

   Workgroup workgroup
   Document document;
   BitSet permissions = new BitSet(2)

   void setPermissions(boolean canRead, boolean canWrite) {
       setReadPermissions(canRead)
       setWritePermissions(canWrite)
   }

   void setReadPermissions(boolean canRead) {
      permissions.set(0,canRead)
   }
   void setWritePermissions(boolean canWrite) {
      permissions.set(1,canWrite)
   }

   boolean getReadPermissions() {
      return permissions.get(0)
   }

   boolean getWritePermissions() {
      return permissions.get(1)
   }


   static belongsTo = [workgroup:Workgroup, document:Document]

   static constraints = {
      workgroup(nullable:false, blank:false)
      document(nullable:false, blank:false)
   }
}
```

I'm getting:

> 2009-11-15 16:46:12,298 [main] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table doc_group_permissions refers to an unmapped class: java.util.BitSet

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

Not all types are mapped - I think this is more of an issue from hibernate side, actually (the ORM layer needs to know how to persist the objects it doesn't know about).

Check out the [joda-time plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time), it comes with a special library that maps the joda Dates classes to hibernate, and then you have to specify it in mapping closure.

You should try to see if somebody wrote a hibernate persister for BitSet, or try to use a different class.

Comment: Do you or anyone happen to know where to find an official set of GORM mapped types?

Comment: Robert Fisher has probably given the most complet list I've seen in his GORM/GSSQL book.

Comment: If you want to implement your own, then here's a starting point http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#types-custom-ut

Comment: This is about the same content as the book. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/JavaTypeVSHibernateType.htm